# Piping into kubectl.exe

Tags: powershell, kubectl

I am trying to run a command like this:

```
kubectl get namespaces -o custom-columns=:metadata.name --no-headers 
       | Where-Object{$_.StartsWith("test") -or $_.StartsWith("dev")} 
       | kubectl get namespaces
```

(NOTE: the line breaks are just for readability, there are no line breaks in my actual command.)

The end goal is to apply a label to a subset of namespaces, but for now, I am just trying to feed the filtered piped list of spaces back in to `kubectl` so it will `get` them.

But I can't seem to get `kubectl` to accept the piped list as the list of namespaces to return.  (this just returns all the namespaces on my cluster).

**How can I get `kubectl` to take the pipe as input?** (So I can filter the list of namespaces.)

Comment: As an aside: your  multi-liner would work as-is in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md); in _Windows PowerShell_ you'd have to place `|` at the _end_ of the intermediate lines.

Comment: @mklement0 - Ha!  How about that!  It does run just fine!  (Still does not have the output I am looking for, but it does work as a multi-line statement.)

Comment:  I'm not familiar with `kubectl`, but [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) make no mention of pipeline (stdin) input. Are you sure it is supported? If you were to pass namespaces as _argument(s)_, what would the syntax be?

Comment: @mklement0 - my guess is that piping is not supported.  I am hoping that if it is not, that there are workarounds.  Passing them as arguments would have them on the end of this command (separated by spaces): `kubectl get namespaces`.  Like this: `kubectl get namespaces dev-namespace1 dev-namespace2 test-namespace1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`kubectl` docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) make no mention of pipeline (stdin) input, so it may not be supported.

You state that passing multiple names *as arguments* can be achieved with appending a space-separated list of names to `kubectl get namespaces`

Therefore, you can simply collect the names in an *array* - which PowerShell automatically does when you collect an external-program call's output in a variable, with each output *line* becoming its own array element<sup>[1]</sup> - and use it as an argument:

```bash
$namespaces =
  kubectl get namespaces -o custom-columns=:metadata.name --no-headers | 
  Where-Object { $_.StartsWith("test") -or $_.StartsWith("dev") } 

kubectl get namespaces $namespaces
```

PowerShell automatically passes an array's elements as *individual*,  (stringified) arguments to *external programs*.

---

<sup>[1] If there happens to be just *one* line of output, it is collected as-is, i.e., as a `[string]` rather than a single-element array containing that string. However, the approach still works in that case. If you explicitly do need an array, use something like `[array] $namespaces = ...`</sup>

Comment: This will work.  I was hoping to keep it to one command.  But I think that lack of support for pipelines in `kubectl` will have me using this.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Vaccano. You _can_ keep it to a single command if you replace the `$namespaces` arguments with a  command enclosed in `(...)`